# Структурированное считывание данных из PDF файла

Tags: java, android, pdf, csv, itext

Здравствуйте. Есть задача считать данные из PDF файла на Adnroid. Перепробовав несколько библиотек, остановился на `iText` (т.к. только с ней одной не возникло дополнительных проблем). Файл считался и довольно быстро. Однако, считать удалось только сплошной текст. 
Поэтому сам вопрос: можно ли хоть как-нибудь считать структурированные данные при помощи этой библиотеки (или какой-нибудь другой)? Сама структура PDF файла такова: [image: Пример]

Т.е. идет header, а потом идут данные в ячейках таблицы, периодически разделенные датой. Вот как выглядит сейчас считывание данных в обычный *.txt файл.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path + "//files//timetable.pdf");

PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(path + "//files//result.txt"));


TextExtractionStrategy strategy;

for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
strategy = parser.processContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
out.println(strategy.getResultantText());
}

reader.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

З.Ы. нашел библиотеку TabulaPDF, но ее использование на Android невозможно из-за привязки в awt.
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

**UPD1**
Пока не было решения с PDF, используя десктопную версию TabulaPDF через графический интерфейс перевел PDF в CSV и легко считал с него данные при помощи OpenCSV. Возможно, кто-то знает способ сделать такую конвертация на самом устройстве?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

к сожалению нет, практически никак нельзя. В очень редких случаях PDF может держать какую-то структурированную информацию о таблицах - если мне память не изменяет, можно, например сохранить AI файл как PDF, не убивая структуру (текст/таблицы), но как правило pdf рендерится в готовые для печати вектора+текст (поэтому его трудно редактировать  и при копировании из PDF приходится удалять переносы строк :-), поэтому общего решения нет, только AI/OCR